# Problem I2C when using BH1750 photoresistor

Tags: python, pi-2, i2c, raspbian-buster, update

(Raspberry Pi 2, model B, V1.1 - buster OS - all updated / upgraded - smbus loaded on)

Hi,

I am quite new to the Raspberry Pi and recently I have hit a brick wall. I am trying to link the Raspberry Pi to a BH1750 photoresistor following this tutorial: https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/03/bh1750fvi-i2c-digital-light-intensity-sensor/

However, the I2C is not recognising it. When I type in the command: `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` , instead of coming up with address 23, it outputs many addresses onto the screen.

I have checked connections, soldered the the pins onto the bh1750, but no change. Even used a different Raspberry Pi (Pi3, model B+), still no good.

I have attached some images of the setup. Any help would be gratefully received as I have run out of ideas on this one.

Much appreciated,

1. https://images.wgsbcomputing.com/20200516_002041.jpg
2. https://images.wgsbcomputing.com/20200516_002133.jpg
3. https://images.wgsbcomputing.com/20200516_004643.jpg
4. https://images.wgsbcomputing.com/20200516_004742.jpg

Comment: It is unclear from the broken link what you are trying, but a 5 year old post for an obsolete OS is unlikely to apply.

Comment: Could you tell me what you mean by a 5 year old post, an obsolete os? The post has been put on today and I have recently upgraded from stretch to raspbian buster a few weeks ago. Not sure about a broken link if you would like to explain?

Comment: Did you do a fresh install of Buster? Upgrading is not recommended.

Comment: No, I followed a tutorial to update it from Stretch. Appears to have worked with a BME280 (temp, humidity, air pressure sensor) which pickes up address x77. Not so with the BH1750 photoresistor though.

Comment: Sorry Milliways, here is the link: https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/03/bh1750fvi-i2c-digital-light-intensity-sensor/

Comment: Does `i2cdetect` show **all** addresses or just some (maybe those above 23)? When several devices are found on a scan then the problem is often that SCL remains on low. Do you use pullup resistors for the bus?

Comment: Try tying the address pin (addr) to ground.

Comment: Rpi Spy tutorial and RoHM datasheet are OK: (1) Using BH1750FVI Light Sensor - matt, RpiSpy 2015
https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/03/bh1750fvi-i2c-digital-light-intensity-sensor/

(2) I2C Ambient Light Sensor IC - RoHM Semi
https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/348/bh1750fvi-e-186247.pdf. Now ***troubleshooting suggestions***: (a) remove BH1750 photoresistor and test another I2C device, to make sure "i2cdetect - y 1" can detect the other device's address. Let me know if you don't have any other I2C device in hand to do swap testing, I can suggest other troublsshooting tricks. Cheers,